# Rsync over sshfs skips filenames starting with underscore

Tags: ubuntu, mac-osx, rsync, synchronization, sshfs

I'm trying to sync a directory tree from OS X (10.11) to Ubuntu 14.04. While most of the files get transferred just fine, files with names starting with `_` (underscore) do not.

Here is the command I use:

```
rsync -rtvh --progress ~/Pictures/processed/ ~/mnt/processed/
```

And an example of the output:

```
sending incremental file list
_MG_7425.jpg
      4.66M 100%  169.79MB/s    0:00:00 (xfr#1, to-chk=58/60)
_MG_7427.jpg
      6.59M 100%  103.07MB/s    0:00:00 (xfr#2, to-chk=57/60)
...
rsync: mkstemp "/Users/user/mnt/processed/._MG_7425.jpg.0cAYb3" failed: No such file or directory (2)
rsync: mkstemp "/Users/user/mnt/processed/._MG_7427.jpg.5Gw1vD" failed: No such file or directory (2)

sent 306.24M bytes  received 9.46K bytes  122.50M bytes/sec
total size is 306.17M  speedup is 1.00
rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1249) [sender=3.1.2]
```

My rsync is installed from homebrew, version info:

```
rsync  version 3.1.2  protocol version 31
Copyright (C) 1996-2015 by Andrew Tridgell, Wayne Davison, and others.
Web site: http://rsync.samba.org/
Capabilities:
    64-bit files, 64-bit inums, 64-bit timestamps, 64-bit long ints,
    socketpairs, hardlinks, symlinks, IPv6, batchfiles, inplace,
    append, ACLs, xattrs, iconv, symtimes, no prealloc, file-flags
```

The remote location is mounted using `sshfs`:

```
sshfs -o idmap=user username@hostname:/some/path ~/mnt -o auto_cache,reconnect,defer_permissions,noappledouble
```

Copying one of the skipped files using `cp` command succeeds. I tried adding `--iconv=utf-8-mac,utf-8` and `--include '_*'` options which had no effect.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: To rule it out, I would avoid sshfs. It's dogdy in my experience. If you have SSH access, you can rsync over ssh directly.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out to the sshfs, that did it. I realize rsync does not need sshfs but I wanted to figure out the source of the issue.

Comment: In case someone found this while search for similar issue with cryptomator, see https://github.com/cryptomator/cryptomator/issues/802#issuecomment-475937418

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out the culprit was in the `sshfs` flags. The `noappledouble` flag I was using to get rid of `.DS_Store` files was actually interfering with `rsync`'s work.

From the [sshfs Mount Options docs:](https://github.com/osxfuse/osxfuse/wiki/Mount-options#noappledouble)

> **noappledouble**
>
> This option makes osxfuse deny all types of access to Apple Double (`._`) files and `.DS_Store` files. Any existing files will become apparently non-existent. New files that match the criteria will be disallowed from being created.

As it points out, the option is also concerned with the `._` name prefix, which is exactly what `rsync` happened to use for its temporary files:

```
rsync: mkstemp "/Users/user/mnt/processed/._MG_7425.jpg.0cAYb3" failed: No such file or directory (2)
```

Thus, when `mkstemp` was creating the temporary file, `sshfs` interfered and blocked it's creation.

Removing `noappledouble` option from the `sshfs` mounting command fixed the issue and the `_*` files have been transferred fine.

Thanks to @Halfgaar for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Nice catch ! musn't have been easy to pinpoint.